# R function read.csv failing with "scan() expected 'a real', got..." message

Tags: r, csv, read.csv

This issue has been raised before and I’ve tried their suggestions, but I think my case is of special interest.  I’ve used read.table, read.csv, and read.csv2.  To no avail.  I choose read.csv2 because the fields/variables are separated with ‘;’, which is the default separator for read.csv2 (albeit you can see I’ve explicitly set it as a workaround)

The first row of the dataset is:

```
16/12/2006;17:24:00;4.216;0.418;234.840;18.400;0.000;1.000;17.000
```

My read.csv2 is:

```
foo <- read.csv2(“dataset.txt",sep=";",stringsAsFactors=FALSE,na.strings='NULL',colClasses=c(rep("character",2),rep("numeric",7)))
```

I’m looking to import the date and time values as strings and explicitly coerce them into date and time:

```
y <- as.Date(foo[,1],"%d/%m/%Y")
x <- strptime(foo[,2],"%H:%M:%S")
```

My problem is that I cannot get past the read.csv2.  The error is:

> ```
> Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
>   scan() expected 'a real', got '4.216'
> ```

Here’s what’s cool.  Note the message says “expected 'a real', got '4.216’”.  Folks, 4.216 is a real.  And note 4.216 is indeed the third value of the row.  I’ve also tried:

```
foo <- read.csv2(“dataset.txt",sep=";",stringsAsFactors=FALSE,na.strings='NULL',colClasses=c(“character”,”character”,rep("numeric",7)))
```

My version of R is  R 3.4.1 GUI 1.70 El Capitan build

Anyone have any ideas of what the problem is?  Or is this just flat out a bug?

Comment: From the documentation: "(read.csv2) the variant used in countries that use a comma as decimal point and a semicolon as field separator.". Rarely are `read.csv` and `read.csv2` good choices over simply using `read.table` and specifying the arguments yourself. Because people rarely actually read what `read.csv` and `read.csv2` are actually doing, so they get confused.

Answer (score 3):

`read.csv2` also changes the decimal point indicator from `.` to `,` (see `dec=","`). Thus a "real" value in this format would look like `4,216`, not `4.216`. Better just stick to `read.csv(..., sep=";")`

```
read.csv("dataset.txt", sep=";", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, na.strings='NULL')
```

Comment: Personally, I hate all the `.csv` and `.delim` "helpers" and just always use `read.table` so that I know exactly what I'm asking for.

Comment: In my case I was using `read.csv` but, for some unknow reason, with `dec=","`.