# rKIN - CSV read error - "Error in scan(text = lst[[length(lst)]], quiet = TRUE) : scan() expected 'a real', got '___'"

Tags: r

I'm attempting to use the rKIN package to analyze bulk stable isotope data. I've managed to use my own data before, but I've since added in some additional data to the csv I was importing and I'm getting an error I can't understand.

"Error in scan(text = lst[[length(lst)]], quiet = TRUE) : scan() expected 'a real', got '14.214750852383951.'
Error in (function (msg)  : TopologyException: side location conflict at -19.569000209142544 14.214750852383951. This can occur if the input geometry is invalid."

This error occurs after the first step of the analysis, using the test.kin command to estimate niche overlap between species. I have tried reformatting the table in a variety of ways, then checking to make sure the columns Ave_C and Ave_N are read as numeric, checking for NAs, etc. Nothing has worked so far but I'm not sure if I'm just missing something obvious?

Data table used - titled multi_species_data

```
                    Species              Habitat  Ave_C Ave_N
1               Esox lucius             Riverine -22.62 13.63
2               Esox lucius             Riverine -23.79 13.99
3  Melanogrammus aeglefinus       North Atlantic -13.37 14.19
4  Melanogrammus aeglefinus       North Atlantic -13.81 14.12
5  Melanogrammus aeglefinus       North Atlantic -13.42 14.02
6  Melanogrammus aeglefinus       North Atlantic -13.08 15.03
7  Melanogrammus aeglefinus       North Atlantic -13.02 14.92
8  Melanogrammus aeglefinus       North Atlantic -13.15 14.01
9  Melanogrammus aeglefinus       North Atlantic -13.25 14.20
10              Esox lucius             Riverine -21.30 13.09
11              Esox lucius             Riverine -20.71 12.40
12              Esox lucius             Riverine -20.82 12.95
13              Esox lucius             Riverine -20.39 12.47
14 Melanogrammus aeglefinus       North Atlantic -13.93 14.31
15 Melanogrammus aeglefinus       North Atlantic -13.21 14.37
16        Anguilla anguilla Catadromous riverine -20.01 11.30
17                  Gadidae       North Atlantic -12.18 15.59
18 Melanogrammus aeglefinus       North Atlantic -14.94 14.35
19             Gadus morhua       North Atlantic -12.72 16.36
20              Esox lucius             Riverine -24.02 17.10
21             Gadus morhua       North Atlantic -11.84 17.47
22 Melanogrammus aeglefinus       North Atlantic -12.40 15.14
23             Gadus morhua       North Atlantic -13.51 16.41
24              Esox lucius             Riverine -25.11 12.70
25        Anguilla anguilla Catadromous riverine -14.67 11.61
26        Anguilla anguilla Catadromous riverine -13.82 13.45
27        Anguilla anguilla Catadromous riverine -13.59 13.19
28        Anguilla anguilla Catadromous riverine -13.83 12.98
29        Anguilla anguilla Catadromous riverine -25.46 16.43
30        Anguilla anguilla Catadromous riverine -24.52 12.98
31        Anguilla anguilla Catadromous riverine -24.59 13.74
32              Esox lucius             Riverine -22.46 13.55
33             Gadus morhua       North Atlantic -15.83 14.40
34 Melanogrammus aeglefinus       North Atlantic -13.88 13.83
35 Melanogrammus aeglefinus       North Atlantic -14.53 13.32
36        Anguilla anguilla Catadromous riverine -11.34 14.82
37              Esox lucius             Riverine -19.93 13.34
38 Melanogrammus aeglefinus       North Atlantic -13.58 14.64
39 Melanogrammus aeglefinus       North Atlantic -14.76 13.65
40 Melanogrammus aeglefinus       North Atlantic -13.73 13.88
41 Melanogrammus aeglefinus       North Atlantic -13.82 13.79
42 Melanogrammus aeglefinus       North Atlantic -13.67 13.48
43        Anguilla anguilla Catadromous riverine -16.14 13.38
44 Melanogrammus aeglefinus       North Atlantic -12.64 12.56
45                  Gadidae       North Atlantic -12.30 13.76
46                  Gadidae       North Atlantic -11.55 14.08
47 Melanogrammus aeglefinus       North Atlantic -13.74 14.11
48 Melanogrammus aeglefinus       North Atlantic -12.02 13.83
49 Melanogrammus aeglefinus       North Atlantic -12.67 14.55
50                  Gadidae       North Atlantic -12.51 14.19
51 Melanogrammus aeglefinus       North Atlantic -12.97 13.59
52        Anguilla anguilla Catadromous riverine -19.76  9.62
53 Melanogrammus aeglefinus       North Atlantic -12.55 13.44
54 Melanogrammus aeglefinus       North Atlantic -12.44 13.53
55             Gadus morhua       North Atlantic -13.20 14.63
56        Anguilla anguilla Catadromous riverine -19.72  9.51
57 Melanogrammus aeglefinus       North Atlantic -12.40 13.47
58             Gadus morhua       North Atlantic -11.78 13.50
59 Melanogrammus aeglefinus       North Atlantic -13.25 13.76
60              Esox lucius             Riverine -21.92 12.11
61              Esox lucius             Riverine -20.19 11.37
```

First command

```
test.kin<- estKIN(data=multi_species_data, x="Ave_C", y="Ave_N", group="Species", 
                  levels=c(50, 75, 95), scaler=2)
```

Error

```
Error in scan(text = lst[[length(lst)]], quiet = TRUE) : 
  scan() expected 'a real', got '14.214750852383951.'
Error in (function (msg)  : 
  TopologyException: side location conflict at -19.569000209142544 14.214750852383951. This can occur if the input geometry is invalid.
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48194416/r-function-read-csv-failing-with-scan-expected-a-real-got-message) answer your question?